# Adobe Air loading external swf with allowDomain('*') inside

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

**What i have**

Large amount of swfs without it's sources (so i couldn't modify its)

**What i need**

To load and play this swfs with my AIR app.

**The problem**

The problem is that this swfs seems having

```
Security.allowDomain('*')
```

in their source, so they would throw

> SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access
>   this feature.

after i load it. I know that Air doesn't need to use this line, but instead of ignoring or warning on it my full app would stop to executing after loading one of this swfs. If only i could try/catch this string, but as i said i don't have an source of that swfs, so the only thing i could do is to modify my AIR app.

**What i tried**

What i already tried is to catch all errors inside loader by doning

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOErrorHandler);

private function loaderIOErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

but it seems it isn't catch errors inside loader at all

**Update**

I couldn't share one of this swfs, but here is simulation i made that reproduce problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/0spbdzijfpboi47/problematicSwf.swf?dl=0

Here it's init code

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            Security.allowDomain('*');

            tf = new TextField();

            tf.text = 'Me loaded!';

            addChild(tf);
        }
```

As you could see it is crashing on allowDomain inside loaded swf.
And here is how i load it

```
var ctx:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest(path), ctx);
```

Comment: Take a look on [uncaughtErrorEvents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#uncaughtErrorEvents) ...

Comment: @akmozo Thank you for your answer. I tried both the
`loader.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);`

and


`loader.contentLoaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);`

with `event.preventDefautl()` in handler, but nothing work and exception still interrupt execution without entering in handlers (my traces inside handler doesn't happen)

Comment: `loader.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler)` should work ! Are you sure that the error is fired from your loaded SWF ? Try to put more details about that error, and if there is a possibility, could you share one of those SWFs ?

Comment: try{} catch(e:UNCAUGHT_ERROR){} statement?

Comment: @quantomworks Thank you for your answer. As i said in question i couldn't modify the source of external swfs, so there is no chance in adding try catch inside it. All i could do is modify AIR app code, but as loader executes code asyncrhonous try catch "loader.load" wouldn't work.

Comment: @user2765683 I saw your SWF and the error also. I'll try to find a solution, if I find one, I'll post it here.

Comment: Sorry about that @user2765683 I didn't catch that. Wish I could help further.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical security restriction but it's a very strict one and it's purpose is to make sure the served swf will never be used outside of what it was made for in the first place.

So the short answer to your problem is this: externally loaded swf that are sandboxed with "Security.allowDomain('*');" will not allow a sandboxed AIR app to interact with them in anyway. Instead those swf will be able to interact with the parent AIR app under restrictions via a sandbox bridge.

If truly you cannot modify those swf then you will never be able to add them to a display list in a AIR app or call any of their methods. A sandbox bridge will also be of no use to you.

It's not the answer you want to hear I bet but it's the only one you'll get.